# ASP page in a div

Tags: asp.net, iframe

Is it possible to load an aspx page in div..? I just want to replace div instead of iframe... Is that possible? then how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `div`s contain HTML, not whole documents.

If you want to load a whole page inside another, you can only use frames.

However, if you are interested in loading document *fragments*, look at [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with ajax. Check out [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

With **Ajax** ?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)